# Installer fails with ambiguous Error 1001. Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service

Tags: windows-services, windows-installer

Greetings!

I have developed a Windows Service that seems to install just fine most of the time. Occasionally, however, I get a popup error during deployment stating

"Error 1001. Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service".

I did some googling and found that this can happen when the Services SnapIn in the MMC is open and can cause some conflicts, though this is now occurring more often without the snapin open at all.

I seem to be able to get the package to install if I reboot after encountering this error.

I ran the MSI with -log enabled, and the output that occurs right as the failure happens is:

```
DEBUG: Error 2835:  The control ErrorIcon was not found on dialog ErrorDialog
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2835. The arguments are: ErrorIcon, ErrorDialog,
Error 1001. Error 1001. Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service.
DEBUG: Error 2769:  Custom Action _450E101F_3B0A_4391_A7F5_3F304BCAA1DF.install did not close 1 MSIHANDLEs.
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2769. The arguments are: _450E101F_3B0A_4391_A7F5_3F304BCAA1DF.install, 1,
```

... any ideas what is causing this problem?

EDIT: REBOOTING and then running the same installer allows it to finish to completion... uninstalling and reinstalling over time will eventually come up with the error again and require a reboot...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1001 always means that you had an Installer Class ( InstallUtil ) custom action fail.  You'll have to debug that code to understand what went wrong.  In all honesty these custom actions are a problem and you should really redesign to get rid of the custom action or refactor it to WiX DTF that provides a better hosting environment for your CA.

Comment: The installer was autocreated by visual studio. There are no custom actions (that I know of)... Any custom actions would

Comment: ... Be generated by vis stud?

Comment: Have you read the log that you posted?  It clearly says the name of the custom action.

Comment: @Rimer: I used to have Installer Class custom actions before in my setup.exe, and it periodically shot me with this type of errors... So, follow Christopher's advice and redesign your install to get rid of this stuff

Comment: Maybe I'm just confused... I never created a custom action for this installer... I assume VS does this for me? Where would I find such an action defined?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using merge modules by any chance? I noticed the GUID in the custom action name and usually this is added only for merge modules.

It seems that the "_450E101F_3B0A_4391_A7F5_3F304BCAA1DF.install" custom action fails with error 2769. This error means "*Custom Action [2] did not close [3] MSIHANDLEs*" and MSDN states:

*The InstallExecuteSequence may have been authored incorrectly. Actions that change the system must be sequenced between the InstallInitialize and InstallFinalize actions. Perform package validation and check for ICE77.*

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372835(VS.85).aspx

So try validating the package with Orca.

Comment: This would not be caused by a merge module as there is no merge module guid in the name of the custom action.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this exact same error "**Error 1001**"

Apparently when i first installed the service, it didn't install correctly. When i deleted the service using **Programs and Features** it did not actually remove the service. So i had to manually delete the service by running "**sc delete [servicename]**" in Command Prompt.

Only after doing that was i able to install the service once more without getting **Error 1001**.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this exact same error "Error 1001".

Apparently, when I first installed the service, it didn't install correctly. When I deleted the service using Programs and Features it did not actually remove the service. So I had to manually delete the service by running `sc delete [servicename]` in Command Prompt.

Only after doing that I was able to install the service once more without getting Error 1001.